# What type of clusters does DLT pipeline use

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

While creating DLT pipeline, we do not specify any cluster. Does DLT pipeline automatically spin up clusters. If yes, what type of clusters does it spin up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the cloud, but typically it selects general purpose computing. For example, on Azure it selected Standard_F8s, on AWS it's c5.2xlarge.

But you can specify your own node types by providing a `cluster` definition as a part of the pipeline ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-configuration.html#cluster-configuration)) - right now it should be done either by editing the JSON representation, or you can do that via [Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/pipeline) as well.

Comment: The dicumentation talks about a default and maintenance clusters. What does these two types signify

Comment: Default cluster is used for actual data processing. Maintenance cluster is used to perform operations like OPTIMIZE, VACUUM, ...